# auto and const object

Tags: c++, constants, auto

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class A
{

    public:
        const shared_ptr<const int> getField () const
        {
            return field_;
        }

    private:
        shared_ptr<int> field_;
};

void f(const A& a)
{
    auto  v = a.getField(); //why auto doesn't a const shared_ptr<const int> here ?
    v.reset(); //OK: no compile error
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    f(a);
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

In the above code why does the compiler deduce `v`'s type as `shared_ptr<int>` and not as `const shared_ptr<const int>` the type returned by getField?

**EDIT:**
MSVC2010

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138588/c0x-auto-what-if-it-gets-a-constant-reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto` ignores references and top level `const`s. If you want them back, you have to say so:

```
const auto v = a.getField();
```

Note that `getField` returns a copy of `field_`. Are you sure you dont want a reference to `const`?

```
const shared_ptr<int>& getField () const;

auto& v = a.getField();
```

Comment: why don't you write: const auto& v = a.getField(); ?

Comment: Because the `const` is automatically inferred in this case.

Comment: That could probably benefit from some clarification. Superificially if I take `const int&`, ignore the reference (`const int`) and the now top level const I get `int`.

Comment: what is a const which it is not qualified "top level" ?

Comment: **Top-Level Const:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers

Answer (score -1):

In the new C++11 standard I think the `auto` keyword used in this context is substituted by the compiler for whatever type `a.getField()` returns. It's a shortcut for the programmer.

See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_inference)

Comment: But the `const` is **not** considered part of the type returned by `a.getField()`.  I tested it today with an online C++14 compiler.