# Auto reference for const array

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, auto

I'm getting into C++11 and really can't understand why this happens:

```
const int arrSource[4] = { 5,7,6,4 };
for (auto& i : arrSource) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
    ++i; //error
}
```

It says that `i` must be a modifiable lvalue and `i`: you cannot assign to a variable that is `const`.

So it means, that if the `arrSource[]` is `const`, it makes `i` `const` too?

Comment: Replace `auto&` with `auto`.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi I know this, but thank you! Just couldn't get why it doesn't work with reference.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138588/c11-auto-what-if-it-gets-a-constant-reference) answer. It explains that `auto&` retains the constness of whatever it refers to and `auto` does not. That is why removing the `&` works.

Comment: @JuliaStefanyshyna If you remove the reference you are actually creating and using a new object via copy-initialization. Which is of course allowed to be modified as it's not const.

Comment: Or to make it short: You can't have a non-const reference to an object that is const itself in the same context.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi shame, that I didn't see this answer before. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So it means, that if the `arrSource[]` is `const`, it makes `i` `const` too?

Yes, if the array is const, each element in the array is also const.

The `auto&` deduces the type based on the initialiser, in this case it is deduced to be `int const&` and hence cannot be modified.

The increment is probably not needed (not sure on your intent). The range based `for` loop takes care of the incrementing between iterations.

If modification of the array is intended (via `i`), then you need to remove the `const`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why I couldn't get this!

Answer (score 2):

N4567 § 3.9.3 [basic.type.qualiﬁer] p6

> Cv-qualiﬁers applied to an array type attach to the underlying element type, so the notation “*cv* T”, where
>   T is an array type, refers to an array whose elements are so-qualiﬁed. An array type whose elements are
>   cv-qualiﬁed is also considered to have the same cv-qualiﬁcations as its elements.