# SFINAE fails with template non-type reference argument

Tags: gcc, clang, c++17, sfinae, non-type

Consider this code:

```
constexpr int XX = 10;

template < auto& II > struct Ban { };
template < auto& II >
std:: true_type test(Ban<II>*);
std::false_type test(...);
```

and:

```
using BB = decltype(test(std::declval<Ban<XX>*>()));
```

Here I am expecting `BB` to be `std::true_type`, but it is `std::false_type` for both `gcc-8.3` and `clang-8.0`. Is this a bug in these compilers?

Note that `BB` becomes `std::true_type` when I change `auto&` to `auto`. Also note that for `gcc` situation is the same if I use `int const` instead of `auto`, so `int const&` yields to `std::false_type`, while `int const` yields to `std::true_type`, while for `clang` `int const&` yields to `std::true_type`. You can find live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GbOIBx).

Is there a workaround to do this kind of SFINAE with a template of non-type reference? The point is to have a utility like `IsInstantiationOfBan`.

Comment: I can't really see anything in the Standard that clearly states how template argument deduction works for a non-type template parameter containing a placeholder type.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of `auto &` you want `decltype(auto)`:

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int XX = 10;

template <decltype(auto) II > struct Ban { };
template <decltype(auto) II >
std::true_type test(Ban<II>*);
std::false_type test(...);

int main()
{
    using BB = decltype(test(std::declval<Ban<(XX)>*>()));
                                           // ^  ^ be careful for brackets!

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<BB, std::true_type>);

    return 0;
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u62ujJ19zwRZ72zs)

In case of your first question, clang probably requires the `const` specifier before `auto &` to fulfil const correctness (constexpr variable is also presumably `const`). [[example]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aBUiHeRyQUbxaSYS).

Comment: This is a Clang bug I suspect, isn't it?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Indeed it wasn't explicilty staded in my answer was it :)? `auto &` should also match to `const`. Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138588/c11-auto-what-if-it-gets-a-constant-reference) can do as a reference.

Comment: thanks! I was worried that `auto` in template parameters for no reason could use different rules than `auto` elsewhere. Since this is C++, that wouldn't surprise me at all.